# AmCharts set to always display labels on stacked columns

Tags: charts, bar-chart, amcharts

I am trying to make my stacked column amChart always display value labels on the columns. Even if they do not fit.

I am using this code:

```
var qtrchart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "none",
"legend": {
    "autoMargins": false,
    "borderAlpha": 0.2,
    "equalWidths": false,
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "markerSize": 10,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "valueAlign": "left",
    "valueWidth": 0
},
"dataProvider": [{
    "QTR":"FY14 Q2",
    "DSAT":0.032602706911007306,
    "Neutral":0.069205892921307938,
    "CSAT":0.89819140016768484},
    {"QTR":"FY14 Q3",
    "DSAT":0.038609212354234618,
    "Neutral":0.060273567620017982,
    "CSAT":0.90111722002574746},
    {"QTR":"FY14 Q4","DSAT":0.038757557172180282,
    "Neutral":0.058425780441887579,
    "CSAT":0.90281666238593217},
    {"QTR":"FY15 Q1",
    "DSAT":0.12391774891774893,
    "Neutral":0.10355411255411255,
    "CSAT":0.77252813852813851}],
"valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "100%",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "position": "left"
}],
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[percents]]%</span>",
    "fillColors": "#87898b",
    "lineColor": "#87898b",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "fontSize": 11,
    "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "title": "DSAT",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "DSAT"
}, {
    "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[percents]]%</span>",
    "fillColors": "#822980",
    "lineColor": "#822980",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "fontSize": 11,
    "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "title": "Neutral",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Neutral"
}, {
    "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[percents]]%</span>",
    "fillColors": "#0096d6",
    "lineColor": "#0096d6",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "fontSize": 11,
    "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "title": "CSAT",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "CSAT"
}],
"marginTop": 30,
"marginRight": 0,
"marginLeft": 0,
"marginBottom": 40,
"autoMargins": false,
"categoryField": "QTR",
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0
},
"percentPrecision": 1,
"data_labels_always_on": true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cww3D/288/

Is there a way to achieve this? I found older versions had a special parameter "data_labels_always_on" that you could set to true. But that does not work.
[image: How do I display amChart labels even if they do not fit on columns?]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the labels to display by setting the `graphs` label position, like this:

```
"labelPosition": "bottom"
```

here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cww3D/291/

Apparently, this forces the labels to display, while the one you'd expect, `"showAllValueLabels": true` does not.

Weird!

Answer (score 5):

I'm using AmChart also, and found this that may help you, that goes on "graph" options:

```
showAllValueLabels  Boolean false   If graph's type is column and labelText is set, graph hides labels which do not fit into the column's space. If you don't want these labels to be hidden, set this to true.
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I also found that parameter, eventually. It did not work as advertised. The values still do not get displayed when set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The text labels are not showing because the font size assigned is larger than the space allowed.  Modifying the "fontSize" property in the first two of the three "graphs" objects from 11 to 3 displays the percent values you are looking for.  However, the font size is so small it isn't very legible even in the fourth column.  It's not a solution, but maybe a starting point for you to investigate further?

No screen cap, sorry, I'm still new here.

Comment: I tried that and it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the code of amChart that automatically hides the text when it does not fit. I need to disable that!